# share env-entry between multiple ejb

Tags: java, dependency-injection, glassfish, jndi, ejb-3.1

I am currently working on a project with multiple ejb and one ejb-jar.xml. I wonder how to share the env-entry from the ejb-jar.xml between the various ejbs.

example :

I have the following ejb-jar.xml

```
<session>
  <ejb-name>MyBeanA</ejb-name>
  <ejb-class>com.enterprise.MyBeanA</ejb-class>

  <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>myVar</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>some value for my var</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
</session>
```

When in the MyBeanA I use :

```
@Ressource
private SessionContext context;
```

I can get the value of myVar with the following code :

```
String myVar = (String) context.lookup("java:comp/env/myVar");
```

Is there a way to get the value of myVar in another ejb like MyBeanB ?

Comment: I finally choose to put the shared data on some properties files so that they are accessible from every ejb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.  There was supposed to have been a section of the assembly-descriptor where you could do this, but I see now we must have missed that before the spec went final.  Shame.  Will bring that up in the EG and cross my fingers it isn't too late to fix for EJB.next.

In the meantime if you have an ear, you can declare them in the application.xml and it will be available in java:app/.  If you have EJBs in a .war file, you can do it in the web.xml and the EJBs will be able to see them in either java:comp or java:module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you think it will be long before being available ?